# How to solve Moment InjectionToken issue?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, calendar, momentjs

I am trying to make an UI project to show a work week (Monday - Friday) view calender. The user can book appointments for any time for any date in the work week. Example - I am trying to make the calender view like in Outlook/MS Teams calender.

I have researched many example and did not found and proper straight forward libraries which does this work. I found a library named `angular-calendar` which is helping to achieve the same view with some minor tweaks. This [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-calendar-scheduler-demo-aqzvcn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) had almost done the same requirements I need for my project.

I tried to re-create the project in my local system which upgraded versions of the libraries used here (Angular version used v15) but getting **Moment** errors.

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(e)[e -> InjectionToken Moment -> InjectionToken Moment -> InjectionToken Moment]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Moment!
    at hm.get (main.js:1:43909)
    at ym.get (main.js:1:46712)
    at ym.get (main.js:1:46712)
    at ym.get (main.js:1:46712)
    at jD (main.js:1:17562)
    at ze (main.js:1:17663)
    at e.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1:240888)
    at ym.hydrate (main.js:1:48078)
    at ym.get (main.js:1:46664)
    at Vb.get (main.js:1:66293)
```

I tried to Google the error but did not found any answers regarding the Moment issue.

Dependencies I am using in my local:

```json
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.31.0",
    "angular-calendar-scheduler": "^15.1.0",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^8.0.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^7.0.2",
    "bootstrap": ">=4.4.1",
    "core-js": "2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

The codes are same as it is in the Stackblitz example. How can I solve this?

Also, are there any easy/straight forward libraries in Angular that can help me to solve?

NOTE: I have noticed Syncfusion's examples but came to know those are paid.